# R `Inf` when it has class `Date` is printing `NA`

Tags: r

Consider the following example:

```
structure(NA_real_, class = "Date")
## [1] NA
structure(Inf, class = "Date")
## [1] NA
is.na(structure(NA_real_, class = "Date"))
## [1] TRUE
is.na(structure(Inf, class = "Date"))
## [1] FALSE
```

Both are printing as `NA`.  Is this the expected behavior or is this an error?  It is very annoying to see `NA` for something that won't return `TRUE` for `is.na()`.

Comment: So how exactly _should_ `print.Date` display the "end of times".

Comment: My best guess is because `unclass(structure(Inf, class = "Date"))` is not `NA` Inf is not really `NA`, but it is as far as the Date class goes...or something like that

Comment: I don't see a method for `is.na.Date`.  Not sure if that matters. Very good question!

Comment: @BondedDust What's wrong with printing `Inf`?

Comment: @Gregor, it is a philosophical question. `Inf` basically saying that time is infinite, while `NA` is basically saying "I don't know and I don't have a way to find out".

Comment: Don't even need to `unclass` it:  `as.numeric(structure(Inf, class = "Date"))` returns `Inf` .

Comment: But we do know some things, more than we know about typical `NA`s. `Sys.Date() < structure(Inf, class = "Date")` returns `TRUE` very appropriately.

Comment: I think it is established that R knows that the structure is still Inf. Tracing the source of this behavior: `print.date` -> `format.date` -> `as.POSIXlt`

Answer (score 12):

This is expected behavior. What is *printed* is not what the object *is*.  To be printed, the object needs to be converted to character.  `as.character.Date` calls `format.Date`, which calls `format.POSIXlt`. The *Value* section of `?format.POSIXlt` (or `?strptime`) says:

> The `format` methods and `strftime` return character vectors
>   representing the time.  `NA` times are returned as `NA_character_`.

So that's why `NA` is printed, because printing `structure(NA_real_, class = "Date")` returns `NA_character_`.  For example:

```
R> is.na(format(structure(Inf, class = "Date")))
[1] TRUE
R> is.na(format(structure(NaN, class = "Date")))
[1] TRUE
```

If you somehow encounter these wonky dates in your code, I recommend you test for them using `is.finite` instead of `is.na`.

```
R> is.finite(structure(Inf, class = "Date"))
[1] FALSE
R> is.finite(structure(NaN, class = "Date"))
[1] FALSE
```

Comment: Re "NA times are returned as NA_character_" in the doc, I don't think it's relevant here, since it's not a NA time  `as.Date(Inf)`prints `NA`but `is.na(as.Date(Inf))` prints `FALSE

Comment: I think this goes back to how you define what a "NA time" means. I've seen lots of discussions that `as.Date(Inf)` is *not* a "NA time", but something different instead. I prefer a pragmatic approach, instead of arguing about what it is, or should be. That's why I recommended using `is.finite()` to determine whether or not a Date/POSIXt is valid.