# Using dplyr::group_by() to find min dates with NAs

Tags: r, date, dplyr, na

I'm finding the minimum date within a group.  Many times, the group includes only missing dates (in which case I'd prefer something like `NA` to be assigned).

The `NA`s appear to be assigned correctly, but they're not responding to `is.na()` as I expect.  **When a cell appears as `NA`, the `is.na()` output is unexpectedly FALSE.**

```
library(magrittr)
ds_visit <- tibble::tribble(
  ~subject_id,                   ~date,
           1L,  as.Date("2017-01-01" ),
           1L,  as.Date("2017-02-01" ), 

           2L,  as.Date(NA_character_),        
           2L,  as.Date("2017-01-02" ),

           3L,  as.Date(NA_character_),        
           3L,  as.Date(NA_character_),   

           4L,  as.Date(NA_character_),        
           4L,  as.Date(NA_character_)       
)

ds_subject <- ds_visit %>% 
  # as.data.frame() %>% 
  dplyr::group_by(subject_id) %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(
    date_na     = is.na(date),          # Works as expected
    date_min    = min(date, na.rm=T),   # Works as expected

    date_min_na = is.na(date_min)       # Does NOT work as expected.
  ) %>% 
  dplyr::ungroup() # %>% as.data.frame()
```

`ds_visit` looks correct.  `ds_subject` looks correct to me, except for that last column .

*ds_subject (The last four rows of the last column are unexpected.)*

```
# A tibble: 8 x 5
  subject_id date       date_na date_min   date_min_na
       <int> <date>     <lgl>   <date>     <lgl>      
1          1 2017-01-01 F       2017-01-01 F          
2          1 2017-02-01 F       2017-01-01 F          
3          2 NA         T       2017-01-02 F          
4          2 2017-01-02 F       2017-01-02 F          
5          3 NA         T       NA         F         # Should be 'T'?
6          3 NA         T       NA         F         # Should be 'T'?
7          4 NA         T       NA         F         # Should be 'T'?
8          4 NA         T       NA         F         # Should be 'T'?
```

I've jittered several dimensions without success, including: (a) OS, (b) R version (including [3.4.3 patched](https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/base/rpatched.html)),
(c) [dplyr](https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr) & [rlang](https://github.com/tidyverse/rlang) version (including CRAN and GitHub versions), and (d) `tibble` vs. `data.frame`.  As a temp work around (not shown here), I've converted the date to a character right before finding the min, and then converting back to a date.

*Warning messages (generated from subjects 3 & 4)*:  Even though the warning message says that `Inf` is returned, `NA` appears when printing the dataset.  (This behavior is consistent with `min(as.Date(NA), na.rm=T)`).

```
1: In min.default(c(NA_real_, NA_real_), na.rm = TRUE) :
  no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
2: In min.default(c(NA_real_, NA_real_), na.rm = TRUE) :
  no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
```

Further inspection of the date column seems consistent with the dataset view above.  The type is a date and the last four cells are `NA`, not infinity.

```
> str(ds_subject$date_min)
 Date[1:8], format: "2017-01-01" "2017-01-01" "2017-01-02" "2017-01-02" NA NA NA NA
```

Is this a bug, or am I misusing something?  Is this related `NA` being produced instead of infinity?

### Edit 1

The links below by @eipi10 and @mtoto help me understand better.  Thanks.  I'm not thrilled that 'NA' prints instead of 'Inf', but I'll try to remember that.

To address this specific scenario, is there a better function than [`base::min()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Extremes.html)?

I'd like a function that I could include inside the [`dplyr::mutate()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/dplyr/versions/0.7.3/topics/mutate)/[`dplyr::summarize()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/dplyr/versions/0.7.3/topics/summarise) clause that behaves something like SQL.  (The initial dplyr example still has that `is.na()` problem when `summarize()` replaces `mutate()`).

For example:

```
"
  SELECT 
    subject_id,
    MIN(date) AS date_min
    --MIN(date) OVER (PARTITION BY subject_id) AS date_min --`OVER` not supported by sqlite
  FROM ds_visit
  GROUP BY subject_id
" %>% 
  sqldf::sqldf() %>% 
  tibble::as_tibble() %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(
    # date_min_na_1 = is.na(date_min), #Before conversion back to date (from numeric); same result as below.
    date_min      = as.Date(date_min, "1970-01-01"),
    date_min_na   = is.na(date_min)
  )
```

*Result where missing groups have well-mannered `NA` values that respond as expected to `is.na()`:*

```
# A tibble: 4 x 3
  subject_id date_min   date_min_na
       <int> <date>     <lgl>      
1          1 2017-01-01 F          
2          2 2017-01-02 F          
3          3 NA         T          
4          4 NA         T
```

### Edit 2

I see this question was marked as a duplicate of [R `Inf` when it has class `Date` is printing `NA`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27554410/r-inf-when-it-has-class-date-is-printing-na).  I see a lot of overlap (and I learned a lot from that question and how it was problematic for my initial code), but I believe they're different questions.

This question involves grouping, and returning `NA` when no nonmissing values are present.  I'm not interested in solely `base::min()`.  As written above, ideally `base::min()` is avoided altogether in favor of an established & tested function/approach that behaves more like SQL.

(Although I'm grateful for @alistaire's wrapper around `base:min()` and will use it if an established function/approach doesn't exist.)

Comment: This is weird. If you try `date_min == Inf` it returns `TRUE` for the last four rows. That'd be fine if it actually did put `Inf` in those values as it suggests it's doing, but it appears as `NA`. Something odd is afoot.

Comment: Simpler reprex: `x <- Sys.Date() + Inf; x; is.na(x); x == Inf`

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30128851/why-do-dates-at-infinity-look-like-nas-but-act-like-dates

Comment: Another example, showing what's going on with the `min` function here: `min(as.Date(NA_character_), na.rm=TRUE); as.numeric(min(as.Date(NA_character_), na.rm=TRUE))`.

Comment: These five comments links helped me understand. I've added to the question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The issue is that `min` with `na.rm = TRUE` and all-`NA` values returns `Inf` (`max` equivalently returns `-Inf`), but `print.Date` doesn't have a way to display those values, so it prints it as `NA`, even though that is not the stored value.

```r
min(NA, na.rm = TRUE)
#> Warning in min(NA, na.rm = TRUE): no non-missing arguments to min;
#> returning Inf
#> [1] Inf

x <- min(as.Date(NA), na.rm = TRUE)
#> Warning in min.default(structure(NA_real_, class = "Date"), na.rm = TRUE):
#> no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf

x
#> [1] NA

is.na(x)
#> [1] FALSE

x == Inf
#> [1] TRUE
```

If you like, you can redefine the print method so it prints however you like, e.g.

```r
print.Date <- function(x, ...){
    if(x == Inf | x == -Inf) {
        print(as.numeric(x))
    } else {
        base::print.Date(x, ...)
    }
}

x
#> [1] Inf
```

To actually get the result you want, specify what should be returned if all the values are `NA`:

```r
library(tidyverse)

ds_visit <- data_frame(subject_id = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L), 
                       date = as.Date(c("2017-01-01", "2017-02-01", NA, "2017-01-02", NA, NA, NA, NA)))

ds_visit %>% 
    group_by(subject_id) %>% 
    summarise(date_min = if(all(is.na(date))) NA else min(date, na.rm = TRUE), 
              date_min_na = is.na(date_min))
#> # A tibble: 4 x 3
#>   subject_id date_min   date_min_na
#>        <int> <date>     <lgl>      
#> 1          1 2017-01-01 FALSE      
#> 2          2 2017-01-02 FALSE      
#> 3          3 NA         TRUE       
#> 4          4 NA         TRUE
```

It's not as concise, but is entirely predictable in its behavior.

Comment: Why was this downvoted? It achieves my goals (and as a bonus, doesn't throw warnings).  Is there a danger that I'm not recognizing?